# PHP program weird

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a code which fetches Data base values for a dropdown and slects the value in the dropdown based on the value fetched. For eg: If a member is Active, it selects Active, If a member is Pending, it selects pending.

However, the code is running very funny for some values which are fetched. Though it fetches a correct value that exists in the database, it displays a value which is not correct. For eg, if a member is Cut, it still shows Active in the Dropdown. This is not applicable to all the cases which are Cut.

The code is:

```
$resultDDM  = '<select name="team$membershipID" width="150" onchange="window.location = ';
    $resultDDM .= "'changemembershipstatus.php?id='+this.value+'&return='+window.location;";
    $resultDDM .= '">';

    $resultDDM .= '<option value="' . $membershipID . '--active"';
    if ($selectedStatus == 'active'){ 
            echo "Bad!";
        $resultDDM .= ' selected';
    }
    $resultDDM .= '>Active</option>';

    $resultDDM .= '<option value="' . $membershipID . '--inactive"';
    if ($selectedStatus == 'inactive') {
        echo "Hello";
        $resultDDM .= ' selected';
    }
    $resultDDM .= '>Inactive</option>';

    $resultDDM .= '<option value="' . $membershipID . '--cut"';
    if ($selectedStatus == 'cut'){
        echo "Hi!";
        $resultDDM .= ' selected';
        }
    $resultDDM .= '>Cut</option>';

    $resultDDM .= '<option value="' . $membershipID . '--pending"';
    if ($selectedStatus == 'pending') {
        echo "No";
        $resultDDM .= ' selected';
    }
    $resultDDM .= '>Pending</option>';

    $resultDDM .= '</select>';
    echo $resultDDM;
    return $resultDDM;
```

I really am clueless because rest of the code works absolutely Fine! Is there some issue in the code?

Comment: Where does `$selectedStatus` get set? Is it possible that some of your values are `Cut` and some are `cut` e.g. first letter is uppercase etc?

Comment: Yes!! Thankss... that actually helped me... it was a Small space in the value that was stored but it did not check that in the if loop... "cut " instead of.. "cut"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For eg, if a member is Cut, it still shows Active in the Dropdown. This is not applicable to all the cases which are Cut.`
Looking at your code, you **want** `cut` to have the selected value...

A couple of ideas... To me, there are two possibilities as to why you are getting inconsistent results.

1) You are getting multiple selected values in your select box. As you are putting each `option` in its own `if` statement, it is completely feasible that your data might return two or more cases where you are putting `selected` into the tag (post your resulting HTML, the code that generates `$selectedStatus` and maybe even an example of your data to be sure).

2) Your value for `Cut` might be inconsistent too, you might have whitespace on either end of the string you're comparing to `$selectedStatus` (in which case you should use `trim` when defining the variable) or you could have case inconsistencies e.g. `Cut`, `cut`, `cUt`, `CUT` which would all result in `$selectedStatus != "Cut"`